# Private Bircas Kohanim during Mussaf?

Tags: kohen-priest, blessing, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

One Shabbos during the Chazan's repetition of the Mussaf Shemoneh Esrei, I noticed a guest who is a Kohen (who seemed to be of Sefaradic stock) wrapping his sons in his tallis, with his hands on their heads, apparently giving them a blessing. I assume it has something to do with Bircas Kohanim. (This was in Chutz La'aretz, by the way.) Does anyone have any information about this custom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This custom is shared by almost Sepharadic people (North Africa + Middle East) and it's not specific to Kohen.
Fathers (or Rav or Zaken) bless their son(s) (and/or other people) during Birkat Kohanim.